# Find total number of days within a range using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have to find a 0-30 days range based on date sent value. It needs to be calculated against `currentDate`. I've done the below code. I need to confirm if it is correct.

```
query = query
   .Where(x => (int)(EntityFunctions.DiffDays(currentDate, (DateTime)x.DATE_SENT)) >= 0 
      && (int)(EntityFunctions.DiffDays(currentDate, (DateTime)x.DATE_SENT)) <= 30);
```

Your valuable suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: If `currentDate` is a local variable it may be better to calculate a start and end date and use `x.DATE_SENT >= startDate && x.DATE_SENT <= endDate`

Comment: have you tested it? Have some values in your database some above and some under threshold and test. As a side note if you already decide to use the `DiffDats()` then use query syntax and `let` so you do not need to write this twice

Comment: @GiladGreen The SQL optimizer will ensure it's not actually run twice.  What you suggest would only prevent him from needing to type it out twice.

Comment: I'm using Query Syntax. I need to find the number of days from date sent - current date to be >= 0 and <=30, likewise 31- 60days etc.

Comment: I really don't understand what you need as output, is it to compare the <current date> to the <date sent> and return **True/False** depending on whether the day count differs from the 0-30 range? Can you provide an example with sample values?

Comment: Get all the rows from the datatable based on a column total days. this total days should be within the range 0 - 30 days. In order to calculate that I have a column named date sent. I have to find the difference i.e no. of days between datesent date and current date to be greater than 0 and lesser than 30.

Comment: @BVidhya `var result = query.Where(x => Enumerable.Range(0,30).Contains((int)(currentDate - (x.DATE_SENT)).TotalDays));`

Comment: I get this error on using your code "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] Range(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Comment: @BVidhya are you getting that error during compile time or is it displayed in red before you compile it? what is the type of the variable **query**? You can also try replacing `.Contains((int)(currentDate - (x.DATE_SENT)).TotalDays));` with `.Contains(currentDate.Substract(x.DATE_SENT).Days));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127909/discussion-between-b-vidhya-and-innat3).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Enumerable Range:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now; // Or an other date
DateTime end = start.AddDays(30);
var DateRange =  Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
                  .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
                  .ToArray();
```